# How to remove attribute with Haste

Tags: javascript, haskell, haste

Module `Haste.DOM` contains function `setAttr` for setting attribute of HTML-element:

```
setAttr (fromJust createProfileButton) "form" "registerNewUserForm"
```

It works fine, but how can I *remove* attribute? For example, I have a button with attribute `disabled` and I want to make it enable. I try:

```
setAttr (fromJust createProfileButton) "disabled" ""
```

but it just make this:

```
<button type=submit ... disabled="">
```

I understand that I must *remove* this attribute, but module `Haste.DOM` doesn't contain function `removeAttr`... So what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I found partial solution: I can disable/enable my button via Bootstrap-class, not via an attribute. So, disable:

```
setClass (fromJust createProfileButton) "disabled" True
```

and enable:

```
setClass (fromJust createProfileButton) "disabled" False
```

And it works fine. But what about *removing* an attribute? Is it possible with Haste?